# What should be the minimum value necessory to transfer a ComPacket in TCG Opal IF-SEND/RECV

Tags: security, storage, specifications, opal, tcg-opal

[TCG Opal test document](http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_Storage_Opal_SSC_Certification_Test_Cases_v2_00_r1.00.pdf) (Page No. 5) says that transfer length field in IF-SEND/RECV Command should be "the minimum value necessary to transfer a
ComPacket". I want to know what is the minimum value necessary to transfer a
ComPacket

Comment: You linked to their test spec; do you have their actual protocol specification?

Comment: http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_Storage-Opal_SSC_v2.01_rev1.00.pdf